# Position JTextField via moving Coordinates?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, point

[image]

(The above image is taken from AutoCAD)

My application draws a line on a JPanel using two Point class variables: "startPoint" and "finishPoint".

"startPoint" is set from the first mouse click. Once a starting point has been established the finishPoint variable is set on the position of the cursor. Therefore the line moves/grows dynamically with the mouse movement until the "finishPoint" is finalised by a second mouse click.

During the period where a startPoint has been established and the line dynamically changes I would like to position a JTextField on the line midpoint (well... slightly off-center so it's not obscuring the line) if possible?

I know I'll get shouted at if I try and position a component without the use of a layout manager, but I can't see how a layout manager can help. I would like to position the JTextField using Coordinates. The only way I can think of doing that is to somehow add the textfield into a shape. Beyond that I'm at a loss.

Can someone put me in the right direction?

My code should anybody want to see it:

```
package Drawing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/*
 * An extension to P2PLines. A line from point A to point B but with an     animation.
 */

public class LineAnimation extends JPanel implements MouseListener,     MouseMotionListener
{
    private Graphics g;
    private Point lineStart = new Point(0, 0);
    private Point lineFinish = new Point(0, 0);
    private boolean drawing;
    int globalX = 0, globalY;
    ArrayList<Line2D> edges = new ArrayList<>();

public LineAnimation()
{
    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
    drawing = false;
}

@Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {}   
@Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) 
{
    if (drawing) 
    {
        g = getGraphics();  // Get Graphics content
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        lineFinish.move(me.getX(), me.getY());
        g.drawLine(lineStart.x, lineStart.y, me.getX(), me.getY());
        edges.add(new Line2D.Float(lineStart.x, lineStart.y, lineFinish.x, lineFinish.y));
        drawing = false;
        g.dispose();
    }
    else 
    {
        lineStart.move(me.getX(), me.getY());
        drawing = true;
    }
}

@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);        
    drawPreviousLine((Graphics2D)g);

    if (drawing)
    {g.drawLine(lineStart.x, lineStart.y, globalX, globalY);}
}

private void drawPreviousLine(Graphics2D g)
{
    for(Line2D lines: edges)
    {g.draw(lines);}
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) 
{
    repaint();
    globalX = me.getX();
    globalY = me.getY();        
}

@Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
@Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
@Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
@Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Frame");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    LineAnimation drawingFrame = new LineAnimation();
    frame.add(drawingFrame);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    drawingFrame.addMouseListener(drawingFrame);
    drawingFrame.addMouseMotionListener(drawingFrame);
}
```

}

Comment: Hm, JLayeredPane perhaps?

Comment: Okay, will look into it.

Comment: Of course understand that using JLayeredPane is in fact using null layouts under another guise.